# How to make this effect (parallax on scrolling)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

example https://toccata.com.ua/

How to make this effect (parallax on scrolling)?

```css
#bg { background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-position: top center;
      background-image: url(http://toccata.com.ua/uploads/main-bg.jpg);
      height: 100vh; width: 100vw; top: 0; 
      position: fixed; z-index: -2; 
      /* элемент на заднем плане под body */}
section { background: #fff; }
.container { padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem; }
.image { background: transparent; }
/* в .image больше нет картинки, но сам блок нужен как 
   распорка, занимающая место. */
.image .container { padding: 30vh 1rem 0 1rem;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000, /* тут просто усилил тень */
               0 0 3px #000, 
               0 0 3px #000, 
               0 0 3px #000; }
/* html { scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; } */
body { margin: 0; padding: 0;
       width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;
       overflow-x: hidden; color: #333333;
       background-color: transparent;
       line-height: 1.2; font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       /* <body> должен быть прозрачным */ }
h1 { padding: 0; margin: 0;
     background: #fff; color: #000;
     position: sticky; top: 0; 
     /* Заголовки сделал прилипающими */ }
.image p { color: #fff; }
section { height: 100vh;
    /* Высоту секции поставил по высоте окна, можно поменять */
    /*  scroll-snap-align: start;
     Это принудительно останавливает скрол на нужных местах */}
```

```html
<section class="image">
  <h1>title1</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="bg"></div>
<section class="content">
  <h1>title2</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="content">
  <h1>title3</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scroll eventlistener in javascript to detect a scroll in the DOM

```
addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  document.querySelector("your css selector").style.setProperty("--scroll", pageYOffset / 10 + "px")
})
```

Now you can use variable `var(--scrol)` as a top property to make this effect work